# DataGridView Problems

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a gridview with customized Column, Cell, and Editing Control..

The problem is with my editing control. It does not trigger the return key, but the other keys are find.

I have notice that the default commit action for editing the cell is enter.

Even i am in the EditOnEnter mode, still it does not trigger.

```
switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
```

I need to use the enter because i need to popup a search of the non existent item is entered in the edit mode cell..

Comment: English may not be your first language, but if you want help you'll have to ask clearer questions.

Comment: My point is quite clear..

Comment: In what event you using this code?